# What could be causing my generator to not work?

Tags: generator

Can anyone please give me some advice, we purchased a generator from our local Lidl it's a Parkside brand, I have followed the instructions to the letter and also watched a youtube presentation but still I can't get it going it must be me as this is the second one I've tried as I took the first one back thinking it was faulty, but surely I can't have two dodgey ones.
I put the fuel to on switch the on switch to on put choke on the pull the flywheel and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add oil prior to attempting to start it?

It looks like some models of Parkside generators have an automatic engine cutoff in the event of low oil. This is to prevent operation during oil starvation, which will ruin the engine.

[Parkside geneator manual download (PDF)](http://www.lidl-service.com/static/18129466/70382_EN_EL.pdf)